# Index an array with a ragged indexing list and perform sum/mean reductions

Tags: python, numpy, loops

I have some 2D data where the first axis is time and the second axis is person's ID. Thus the data entries are the persons' property values over time.

What I want to do is to group the persons and average the properties in each group at all time frames. Here is a sample of 6 time points and 5 persons with 2 group

```
import numpy as np

data = np.arange(30)
data.shape = 6, 5
groups = [[0, 1, 4], [2, 3]]
result = np.empty((6, 2))

for i, indices in enumerate(groups):
    result[:, i] = data[:, indices].mean(axis=1)
```

And the `result` is

```
array([[ 1.66666667,  2.5       ],
       [ 6.66666667,  7.5       ],
       [11.66666667, 12.5       ],
       [16.66666667, 17.5       ],
       [21.66666667, 22.5       ],
       [26.66666667, 27.5       ]])
```

Is this the best we can do in terms of efficiency? I was wondering if that looping over the `groups` could also be eliminated.

Comment: The fact that the groups differ in size makes this hard to 'vectorize'.

Comment: what can we do if the group sizes are the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach #1 : Generic case**

Here's an almost vectorized approach making use of [`np.add.reduceat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) -

```
g = np.concatenate(groups)
lens = list(map(len, groups))
cuts = np.r_[0,np.cumsum(lens)[:-1]]
out = np.add.reduceat(data[:, g], cuts, axis=1)/lens
```

**Approach #2 : Specific case**

If `groups` is a regular `2D` array/list, we can simply do -

```
data[:, groups].mean(2)
```

**Approach #3 : Approach 1 + 2**

Mixing approaches 1 and 2  we can come up another generic case method -

```
from itertools import zip_longest

idx = np.vstack(list(zip_longest(*groups, fillvalue=-1)))
c = (idx == -1).sum(0)
sums = data[:, idx].sum(1) - c*(data[:,-1,None])
lens = list(map(len, groups))
out = sums/lens
```

**Approach #4 : With matrix-multiplication**

We will create a mask that when matrix-multiplied with `data`, with its sum-reduction will give us the sum-reduced version and then just divide by the lengths to get our desired average values -

```
mask = np.zeros((data.shape[1], len(groups)), dtype=bool)
for i, indices in enumerate(groups):
    mask[indices,i] = 1
out = data.dot(mask)/list(map(len, groups))
```

Also, we might want to use `float32` for faster matrix-multiplication -

```
data.dot(mask.astype(np.float32))
```

**Approach #5 : Approach 2 + 3**

We will pad with zeros as an additional column, and with a regular indexing array created off `zip_longest`, index and sum and hence get the mean values -

```
data0 = np.pad(data,((0,0),(0,1)))
idx = np.vstack(list(zip_longest(*groups, fillvalue=-1)))
out = data0[:, idx].sum(1)/list(map(len, groups))
```

Comment: Approach #2 doesn't work for me. Do I need to transform `groups` or `data` first?

Comment: @nos As noted, it's a specific case solution, assuming a regular 2D array/list for `groups`.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized 'regular' means array/list with the same number of entries in each row, i.e., rectangular shaped. Thanks very much for this comprehensive answer!